# How do I edit a interface for a 4 inch iPhone while not editing the 3.5 inch

Tags: iphone, xcode, size, screen

So I've made this app, and while submitting I needed to grab 4' screenshots.

I based my app to run on 3,5 inch devices, so I thought, when I'd run it on a 4' there could be letterboxes.

Somehow the interface adapted itself to the 4' screen, but images and labels were misplaced.

When I edit the .xib to look good on the 4' screen the exact opposite happens on the 3.5 screen. Stuff get's misplaced.

While creating my project ( About 20 .xib's ) I always chose "3.5' screen" instead of "Freeform" or the default "4' screen".

Now how do I change it to look good on both screen sizes? Isn't there a way to edit a xib for both sized without having to rebuild it?

Comment: Edit the top 0.5 inch only =P

Comment: of the 4'? The problem is in the bottom, there all the stuff gets misplaced :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Duplicate each XIB and give it a suffix, for example MyViewController.xib -> MyViewController_568.xib
- Re-arrange the new XIBs
- Over-ride initWithNib

  ```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle { 
  if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480) {
      nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_568", nibName];
  }
  if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {

  }
  return self;
  ```

  }